# What is the randomness of Java.nextFloat()

Tags: java, random, probability

Specifically, if used in the form of:

`Random.nextFloat() * N;`

can I expect a highly randomized distribution of values from 0 to N? 
Would it be better to do something like this?

`Random.nextInt(N) * Random.nextFloat();`

Comment: The first one will give an evenly distributed range, the second will be biased towards zero

Comment: Your second solution would mean an uneven distribution, with more values closer to 0;

Comment: p.s. is this java.util.Random? Because I don't believe it has those static methods

Comment: Yeah, I assumed by Random.rand(N) he meant a random integer between 0 and N

Comment: true, but random.rand(N) doesn't exist as a method either, only .nextInt()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single random number from a good generator--and `java.util.Random` is a good one--will be evenly distributed across the range... it will have a mean and median value of 0.5*N. 1/4 of the numbers will be less than 0.25*N and 1/4 of the numbers will be larger than 0.75*N, etc.

If you then multiply this by another random number generator (whose mean value is 0.5), you will end up with a random number with a mean value of 0.25*N and a median value of 0.187*N... So half your numbers are less than 0.187*N! 1/4 of the numbers will be under .0677*N! And only 1/4 of the numbers will be over 0.382*N. (Numbers obtained experimentally by looking at 1,000,000 random numbers generated as the product of two other random numbers, and analyzing them.)

This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

At first, Random in Java doesn't contain rand() method. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). I think you thought about Random.next() method.

Due to your question, documentation says that nextFloat() is implemented like this:

```
public float nextFloat() {
   return next(24) / ((float)(1 << 24));
 }
```

So you don't need to use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Random#nextFloat() will give you an evenly distributed number between 0 and 1.

If you take an even distribution and multiply it by N, you scale the distribution up evenly. So you get a random number between 0 and N evenly distributed.

If you multiply this by a random number between 0 and N, then you'll get an uneven distribution. If multiplying by N gives you an even distribution between 0 and N, then multiplying by a number between 0 and N, must give you an answer that is less or equal to if you just multiplied by N. So your numbers on average are smaller.

Comment: Thanks, I was mainly trying to address the scale of distribution, and whether or not it is a problem.  I wasn't about to write out my thoughts very well.

Comment: You can see the scaling if you want. Draw dots on a page, 1 inch apart. Then underneath, for each dot, double it's distance from the beginning(even draw a line from the original to the new one). You'll see that all of the dots are still evenly distributed over a bigger range